# Continued from nextjs + svgr + jest " Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string or a class/functionbut got: object." An error appears

Tags: svg, next.js

I am currently converting the svg file into a component using svgr, next.js 14 and then writing test code with jest.

LoadingSpinner also uses svg files, and this part passes the test normally.

However, in the case of ModalBannerImage, it keeps saying "Warning: React.jsx: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object." An error appears.

If I delete the current ModalBannerImage and run a test, it works fine.

No matter how many times I try this, the error continues to appear.
Is there a solution?

Even though I was told not to use {} when importing files, the error continues to appear.

- jest.config.js

```js
const nextJest = require('next/jest');

const createJestConfig = nextJest({ dir: './' });

const customJestConfig = {
  setupFilesAfterEnv: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.ts'],
  testEnvironment: 'jest-environment-jsdom',
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.jsx?$': 'babel-jest',
    '^.+\\.svg$': 'jest-transformer-svg',
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '\\.svg$': '<rootDir>/__mocks__/svg.js',
  },
};

module.exports = createJestConfig(customJestConfig);
```

- next.config.js

```js
const { createVanillaExtractPlugin } = require('@vanilla-extract/next-plugin');

const withVanillaExtract = createVanillaExtractPlugin();

/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  webpack: (config, options) => {
    // WAV 파일 처리를 위한 설정
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(wav)$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[name].[ext]',
          publicPath: `/_next/static/sounds/`,
          outputPath: `${options.isServer ? '../' : ''}static/sounds/`,
        },
      },
    });
    const fileLoaderRule = config.module.rules.find((rule) => rule.test?.test?.('.svg'));

    if (fileLoaderRule) {
      config.module.rules.push({
        ...fileLoaderRule,
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        resourceQuery: /url/, // *.svg?url
      });

      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.svg$/i,
        issuer: fileLoaderRule.issuer,
        resourceQuery: { not: [...fileLoaderRule.resourceQuery.not, /url/] },
        use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
      });

      fileLoaderRule.exclude = /\.svg$/i;
    }

    // 나머지 설정
    return config;
  },
  images: {
    domains: ['localhost'],
  },
};

module.exports = withVanillaExtract(nextConfig);
```

- ModalBannerImage.tsx

```js
import DarkLoginModalBannerImage from 'public/images/svgs/DarkLoginModalImage.svg';
import WhiteLoginModalBannerImage from 'public/images/svgs/WhiteLoginModalImage.svg';
import { useAtomValue } from 'jotai';
import { themeAtom } from '@/_store/themeAtom';

export default function ModalBannerImage() {
  const darkTheme = useAtomValue(themeAtom);

  return darkTheme ? (
    <div>
      <DarkLoginModalBannerImage width={280} height={400} />
    </div>
  ) : (
    <WhiteLoginModalBannerImage width={280} height={400} />
  );
}
```

- LoadingSpinner.tsx

```js
import { myStyle } from '@/_styles/vars.css';
import DarkLoadingSpinner from 'public/images/svgs/DarkLoadingSpinner.svg';
import WhiteLoadingSpinner from 'public/images/svgs/WhiteLoadingSpinner.svg';
import { useAtomValue } from 'jotai';
import { themeAtom } from '@/_store/themeAtom';
import { loadingSpinnerContainer, loadingSpinnerText } from './loadingSpinner.css';

export default function LoadingSpinner() {
  const darkTheme = useAtomValue(themeAtom);

  return (
    <div className={`${loadingSpinnerContainer} ${myStyle}`}>
      {darkTheme ? (
        <DarkLoadingSpinner width={300} height={300} />
      ) : (
        <WhiteLoadingSpinner width={300} height={300} />
      )}
      <p className={`${loadingSpinnerText} ${myStyle}`}>잠시만 기다려주세요!</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

- without ModalBannerImage.tsx

[image]

- with ModalBannerImage.tsx

[image]